# show only in the first row in crystal reports details section

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, business-objects

i have a crystal report and there is a field in details section which currently showing for each row. what's the way to set this field to show only once on the very first row?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Right-click on the field in Report Designer, select **Format Field...**, click on the Common tab in the Format Editor dialog, click on the conditional suppression button (the box marked `x-2` to the right of Suppress) and enter the formula `RecordNumber > 1` . Click Save and close to exit the Suppress Format formula editor, then click OK to exit the Format Editor.

Comment: I need to show the first record only on each group - How to do this?

Comment: @Sensa: Try asking it as a new question, rather than a comment on an existing question.

Comment: Hi Mark, As per your advice here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265941/crystal-reports-showing-only-first-record-in-each-group