# Crystal Reports - Show the first 2 records of each group

Tags: database, conditional-statements, formula, record, suppress

I have a number of dated records, sorted by descending date, which are grouped by vehicle. I only want to see the records of the latest two dates on the report.

I'm using this answer from an old question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30184315

I'm using Suppress No Drill-Down on the Details section with
`RecordNumber > 2`. This works perfectly for the first group, but the other groups are now all blank. I have a Page Header, Group Header, Details, and Group Footer.

Is there a way to use RecordNumber > 2 for the details under each group? Maybe some reset on change of group?

Image attached

[Preview on the records. It's grouped by Fleet no, non-bold are the Details section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVunG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Create a **Running Total** called G1_Counter on the Date Field.

Type of summary: **Count**

Evaluate: '**For each record**'

Reset: '**On change of Group**'

Step 2: Set the detail section suppress condition to:

```
{#G1_Counter} > 2
```