# How to make a form and code to only show 1 report per 1 enty data?

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

Im using visualstudio 2010, ms access and crystal report 8.5.
How to code only 1 report per 1 entry data? what i mean for 1 entry data are:
  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093708/show-only-in-the-first-row-in-crystal-reports-details-section): https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5R2C.jpg .

i have 6 entry data atm. this solution works, but it only shows 1st data entry, idk how to show 2nd or 5rd, etc per report[stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093708/show-only-in-the-first-row-in-crystal-reports-details-section). Please let me know your answer completely if after the code, i still need to do that(stack overflow link). Thanks a lot.

My code (cant show other than first entry data):

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Laporanutama
Public CONN As OleDbConnection
Public CMD As OleDbCommand
    Public DS As New DataSet
    Public DA As OleDbDataAdapter
    Public RD As OleDbDataReader
    Public LokasiData As String
    Dim awal As String
    Dim akhir As String
    Dim ae As String

    Sub Koneksi()
        LokasiData = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=distribusi.mdb"
        CONN = New OleDbConnection(LokasiData)
        If CONN.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            CONN.Open()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        CR.ReportFileName = "BPL1.rpt"
        CR.WindowState = Crystal.WindowStateConstants.crptMaximized
        CR.RetrieveDataFiles()
        CR.Action = 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'lap1.Show()
        'CR.ReportFileName = "Stok.rpt"
        'CR.WindowState = Crystal.WindowStateConstants.crptMaximized
        'CR.RetrieveDataFiles()
        'CR.Action = 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

- **//The other code that im trying to show 1 report per data entry are :**

  ```
   Imports System.Data.OleDb
  Public Class LaporanBPL
  Public CONN As OleDbConnection
  Public CMD As OleDbCommand
  Public DS As New DataSet
  Public DA As OleDbDataAdapter
  Public RD As OleDbDataReader
  Public LokasiData As String
  Dim awal As String
  Dim akhir As String
  Dim ae As String


  Sub Koneksi()
      LokasiData = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication14\WindowsApplication14\Database1.mdb"
      CONN = New OleDbConnection(LokasiData)
      If CONN.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
          CONN.Open()
      End If
  End Sub


  Sub TampilTanggal()

      Call Koneksi()
      CMD = New OleDbCommand("select no_kkp from tb_bpl", CONN)
      RD = CMD.ExecuteReader
      Do While RD.Read
          ComboBox1.Items.Add(RD.Item(0))
      Loop
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
      If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
          MsgBox("Pilih dulu Tahunnya")
          Exit Sub
      Else
          CR.SelectionFormula = "({tb_bpl.no_kkp})=" & Val(ComboBox1.Text)
          CR.ReportFileName = "BPL1.rpt"
          CR.WindowState = Crystal.WindowStateConstants.crptMaximized
          CR.RetrieveDataFiles()
          CR.Action = 1
      End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub LaporanBPL_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      Call TampilTanggal()
  End Sub

  Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

  End Sub
  ```

  End Class

Comment: Are you wanting a new page for each data row in the data set, or do you only want  a specific data row to print based upon an input value?

Also, do you have any grouping within you data?

Comment: @R.McMillan each specific data row = 1 report, and 1 report often has 5 pages. I want to make a function to calls one of them(rows) by selecting 1 of them with ComboBox1 (dataset: 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017) then click a button to calls the report (example: select 2015 on ComboBox1 then click a button to calls the report).
Also idk how to grouping, but i think i didnt have it.