# SAP Crystal Reports: Only display the first result in a Subreport

Tags: crystal-reports

Similar to the following posts:

[show only in the first row in crystal reports details section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093708/show-only-in-the-first-row-in-crystal-reports-details-section)

I'm relatively new to Crystal Reports and am still familiarising myself with it.

I have a Sub Report that displays all lines with `Key X` where `Condition Y` is met.
I would like to only display the FIRST dataset.

Is there an easy solution to this?

I'm using SAP Crystal Reports 2013

Currently it appears as:

```
Key
 A
Subreport
 A1
 A2
 A3

Key 
 B
Subreport
 B1
 B2
 B3
```

What I want is:

```
Key
 A
Subreport
 A1

Key 
 B
Subreport
 B1
```

Comment: Show data in subreport header (and hide details)?

Answer (score 0):

In your sub report create a new running total in section: Running Total Fields.
Set the type of summary to: count
Name it: counter

Place this in the details section on the report canvas and see that it works.
This will give you a running counter for every row. 1,2,3,4,5 etc

Right click the Details section and click on: Section Expert

Then click on Suppress X-2 formula icon:

Here you could simply add: **{#counter} > 1**

This will now suppress all rows of data where your new counter > 1

Let us know how it goes and please mark as answered to close out the case.

**Note:** If you have many rows of data in your sub reports then it would be more efficient to create a  SQL Command instead of adding your tables. In the SQL command you could limit the data via pure SQL code. However, if you just have a small data set then the above solution is fine.